# Entity Framework 6.1 Code first from existing DB - add foreign key to T4 template

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, t4

I'm using EF 6.1 new feature - Code first from existing DB - and I'd like to add a foreign key in addition to each navigation property.
I added the default T4 templates from nuget but I cannot figure out how to edit it. I guess it should be a quite common task, but I wasn't able to find any example...
Thanks
Matteo

Comment: Which nuget package did you install?

Comment: This one EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp, as explained in this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn753860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the T4 templates, that are used for generating the entity classes following the instructions from  [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2241). Just follow the instructions from the comment of BriceLambson on Apr 28 at 6:22 PM

You need the following structure in your project:

- CodeTemplates

  - EFModelFromDatabase

    - EntityType.cs.t4

The file EntityType.cs.t4 must contain the contents of the following [link](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EFTools/EntityDesign/CodeGeneration/Generators/GeneratedCode/DefaultCSharpEntityTypeGenerator.tt).

After that you can change the following part:

```
<#
    }

    foreach (var navigationProperty in entityType.NavigationProperties)
    {
        if (!first)
        {
            WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            first = false;
        }

#>
        public virtual <#= code.Type(navigationProperty) #> <#=     code.Property(navigationProperty) #> { get; set; }
<#
    }
#>
```

to something like this:

```
<#
    }

    foreach (var navigationProperty in entityType.NavigationProperties)
    {
        if (!first)
        {
            WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            first = false;
        }

#>
        public int <#= code.Property(navigationProperty) #>ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("<#= code.Property(navigationProperty) #>ID")]
        public virtual <#= code.Type(navigationProperty) #> <#= code.Property(navigationProperty) #> { get; set; }
<#
    }
#>
```

After that you can use - code first from existing database - to generate your entities.

Hope this helps

### UPDATE

Instead of creating the directory structure by hand one can just install the nuget package `EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp` as Matteo Sganzetta did